# How to decipher ss -t command output?

Tags: port-forwarding, ss

I am struggling with Node.js app deployment because of some CORS and port issues.
`ss-t` output

```
ESTAB                       0                        0                                                         [::1]:33366                                                    [::1]:3031 

ESTAB                       0                        0                                                         [::1]:3031                                                     [::1]:33366
```

What are Local Address:Port and Peer Address:Port?

How it comes that port 3031 appears in both roles?

```
sudo ss -ltp

LISTEN           0                 128                                            *:3031                                           *:*                users:(("docker-proxy",pid=16141,fd=4))
```

Where can I read more about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each TCP communication is identified, at each end, by these four values:

```
origin IP - origin port - destination IP - destination port
```

In your case, you have a connection from the host to itself, so you get to see the two endpoints, with their origin and destination ports swapped in the second one.

You can find more information in the Wikipedia article: [Transmission Control Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol). Specifically related to your question: the section on [protocol operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation), that lists the states (connected, listen, ...) and the section on [TCP ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_ports).